# Is there a type in @types/express for Express middleware functions

Tags: node.js, express, typescript2.0, tsc

Right now I have this in a custom .d.ts file:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
export type MiddleWareFn = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void;
```

and I reference that file like so:

```
router.use('/foo', <MiddleWareFn> function(req,res,next){});
```

however I am wondering if Express has typings for middleware functions already?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is how I'm handling it:

```
import type { RequestHandler } from "express";

export const myMiddleware: RequestHandler = (req, res, next) => {
  // HANDLE REQUEST
  // RESPOND OR CALL NEXT()
};
```

Answer (score 50):

Yes. You need to import also `RequestHandler`. Check definition [here](https://github.com/types/express/blob/master/lib/router/index.d.ts#L14)

```
import { RequestHandler } from 'express';
```

Comment: ok. feel free to mark this as the answer of your question. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I am using `RequestHandler` as follows:

```
import type { RequestHandler } from "express";

type ArgumentTypes<T> = T extends (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never;

type RequestHandlerArgs = ArgumentTypes<RequestHandler>;

app.use((...args: RequestHandlerArgs) => {
  const [req, res, next] = args;
  // ...
});
```